# Creating an UDP chat app

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, endpoint

Recently I began reading about UDP and I tried to create my own application in C#. I'm testing it with a client set on an Oracle VM ver. 5.0. I use the same code for the client and server(I set two different UdpClients for sending and receiving). **The problem** is that I don't receive messages on the VM (sent from my computer with windows 10). It only works when I send messages from VM to my system.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;


namespace Trevix
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        delegate void setText_callback(TextBox txt,string input);

        UdpClient client_send,client_receive;
        IPEndPoint brodcast_end = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast , 10000);
        IPEndPoint listen_end = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        Thread listen_thread;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //If object initialized with EndPoint or port it will LISTEN(?)
            // If I want to send data call CONNECT
            client_send = new UdpClient();
            client_receive = new UdpClient(10000); //or new UdpClient(listen_end)?

            client_send.Connect(brodcast_end);

            listen_thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(listen));
            listen_thread.IsBackground = true;
            listen_thread.Start();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] buff = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1.Text );
            client_send.Send(buff, buff.Length);
        }
        
        private void listen()
        {
            byte[] rec_buff;
            IPEndPoint recv_end;

            while (true)
            {
                recv_end = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                rec_buff = client_receive.Receive(ref recv_end);
                setText(textBox2, recv_end.ToString() +": "+ Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rec_buff)+Environment.NewLine );
               
            }
        }


        private void setText(TextBox txt, string input)
        {
            if (txt.InvokeRequired)
            {
                txt.Invoke(new setText_callback(setText), txt,input);
            }
            else
            {
                txt.Text += input;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a few other questions:

1)I'm also not sure about configuring UdpClient as client or server. What is the difference between `UdpClient listener=new UdpClient(10000)` and `UdpClient listener=new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0))`? (I know that '0' as port lets the class to allocate it automaticaly).

2)In this section of code

> recv_end = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
>
> rec_buff = client_receive.Receive(ref recv_end);

the "recv_end" will be replaced with the receiver's address data(ip and port) at runtime. But almost in all examples I saw on internet it was specified that setting the end point's ip value to Any is critical. Why?

Comment: You might mis some chat messages, as UDP could lose datagrams. So you need to create an extra mechanism to check lost packets. TCP/IP would be easier, because it has this mechanism

Comment: I know about this problem but I don't think this is the case. I send multiple messages...not one arrived. And I also tested it with another similar looking app(it had the same thread-search part) and it worked. I have no ideea why it doesn't work the other way. Could it be the VM?

Comment: About your problem: If you use the same code, it looks like a problem of network settings (firewall etc.). About your first question: I don't think `UdpClient listener=new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0))` will work. If the port is choosen automatically, to which port a client should connect?

Comment: Then if I set 10000(the port I choose) instead of 0 it should work right?

Comment: In your code you are using port 10000 `client_receive = new UdpClient(10000);`

Comment: Okay. I recreated the project without using the brodcast option. Now I can send data to the ip I want.It looks like the brodcasting didn't work somehow(maybe the router couldn't send the data to the VM). No ideea what is the problem.

Comment: I think I found the problem. The brodcast value is 255.255.255.255 and it seems it never passes the system(windows 10). I had to use another brodcast(I think it is another version of 255...) ip 192.168.1.255 and it worked. I wonder why....